# What stackexchange site do questions about making custom levels belong on?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do “mod-development” questions belong here?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/562/do-mod-development-questions-belong-here)

I asked a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96230/cannot-create-a-neutral-unit-with-a-trigger) yesterday that relates to a custom level design in a game. I am aware of the GameDev.stackexchange.com website; however, I asked it here because I thought it was more fitting and much more likely to get answered than on the other website for a couple of reasons:

1. It's not really a game development question. It is a question on how to use a level creation tool that comes with the game.
2. It relies highly on knowledge of a specific game, not on being a good game developer. Therefore it requires views from people that know the game, not from people that know how to develop games.

Although the two points were initially why I posted the question here, I can see that it might not be the best website for posting this kind of question. I wonder if there is a better website for it. Should I have asked the question on GameDev.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do "map-editor" questions belong here?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/544/6066)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gamedev.stackexchange is the correct choice for map-making questions.

[As per their meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here), it's within scope.

Comment: alright i will flag my question to migrate it to that site. Hopefully it will receive enough attention there