# Are questions allowed about mods/conversions/rom hacks?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are questions about prominent mods on topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/are-questions-about-prominent-mods-on-topic)

Can we ask questions here about fan-created additions or changes to games? It's obvious for series like The Elder Scrolls that user modding is encouraged through providing a creation toolbox, but it could be argued couple of other very popular user-created additions are treading a fine line between modding and copyright infringement/piracy (e.g rom hacks). Is there a site policy on this?

Comment: I see no problem personally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about mods from gamers' perspective are okay, as outlined here:

- [Are questions about mods on topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/are-questions-about-prominent-mods-on-topic) (yes)

Questions about developing mods or creating maps aren't, as outlined here:

- [Do "mod-development" questions belong here?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/562/do-mod-development-questions-belong-here) (no)
- [Do "map-editor" questions belong here?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/544/do-map-editor-questions-belong-here) (no)

Questions about emulators are okay, but linking to ROMs or ROM sites usually isn't, as outlined here:

- [What's the official stance on console emulation?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/whats-the-official-stance-on-console-emulation)

So the only thing remaining in your question are questions about mods that "are treading a fine line between modding and copyright infringement". In those cases I don't think it's any of our problem - the mod authors might be infringing but I think it's okay to ask questions in this site about those mods, from a gamer's perspective.